# How to select an element using last-of-type and a class name

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I need to get the last span with the class `pos`

At the moment I am using the following code

```
   inner.append('<span class="pos"></span>');
```

.... some other code here

```
   var posSpan = inner.find('span:last-of-type').position().left;
```

Could you suggest me how to add the class `pos` when selcting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery function [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

`$('span.pos').last()`

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will be same element as you have just appended, so

```
var span = $('<span class="pos"></span>').appendTo(inner)
var posSpan = span.position().left;
```

Comment: sorry I did not mention that before posSpan I have others appends

Comment: @GibboK that does not matter... here you are having a reference to the span directly... I don't think you are adding any other `span.pos` after that right

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var posSpan = $('span.pos:last');
```

or

```
var posSpan = $('span.pos').last();
```

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight i have used last() function check man